# how can I to get controls back on my first page after server.execute("../../abc.aspx"). I have to show an alert after server.execute()

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

This is my Code, After `Server.Execute()` my popup does not show.

```
protected void Generate_cola_letter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Server.Execute("../ABC.aspx");
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create a Message box?

this is an example of a message box in asp.net

```
string script = "alert(\"Your Message.\");";

            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),
                "ServerControlScript", script, true);
```

Comment: No my actual question was that how to get back control on the previous page. because after server.execute() no popup works, I tried other methods but after server.execute() nothing works. not even visible="true" or "false".

Comment: this is your pop up right? `Server.Execute("../ABC.aspx");`?Does this work?

Comment: you could try replacing `Server.Execute("~/Abc.aspx");`

Comment: If this helped you.Please mark it mark this as answered.

Comment: my pop up works if I remove Server.Execute() but after it. my pop up does not works. even a simple. visible true false does not works.